# Value cannot be null. (DataGridView)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have some problems deleting a record from `DataGridView`. When I run the program, this is what it always show:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

This is my code by the way:

```
if (dgvBrand.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
        {
            model.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvBrand.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value); //I tried to breakpoint this one and it has '0' value.
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (SOMSEntity db = new SOMSEntity())
                {
                    model = db.brands.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                    var entry = db.Entry(model);
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                        db.brands.Attach(model);
                    db.brands.Remove(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    DisplayDGV();
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way how to fix this thing?

Comment: In which point you are getting error ?

Comment: `var entry = db.Entry(model);` this one.

Comment: When I also run the program, it also show this one: `entry = null, db={SOMSEntity}, model=null`

Comment: Is there any brands which has 0 Id?

Comment: No. I have 3 records in the database. And all of them has `ID` values.

Comment: You are getting null in  model = db.brands.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID).FirstOrDefault(); Look at answers

Comment: how can I get the value of it?

Comment: Did you check your dgvBrand.CurrentRow? If you in new row of DataGrid dgvBrand.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value will be null

Comment: I just want to get the value of the current `DataGridView`. That's the only thing I need to fix.

Comment: I get it now I just checked my `DataGridView` columns and I forgot to put `ID` field in `DataPropertyName`. I guess my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your `model` is null. Avoid id before delete

```
using (SOMSEntity db = new SOMSEntity())
{
     model = db.brands.Where(x => x.ID == model.ID).FirstOrDefault();
     if(model == null) // throw NotFound or return         

     var entry = db.Entry(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Where`, you can use the below code and have a check for `null` before using the `model` variable.

```
model = db.brands.employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == SomeVariable);

if(model!=null)
{
```

Also, I think you should use a different variable. `model.ID` can also be problematic.